# How do I force update and app flawlessly?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-update-app

We have an ionic-capacitor app. The issue is that after we are updating a new version of the app to the play store and receiving the confirmation email that it has been uploaded, for some devices the update is not available.

Meaning, when user loads the app, we send him to the store to update, but he can't do that, therefore the user is stuck in a loop.

Comment: do you mean uploaded or actually confirmation says it was deployed and is now available for all users?

Comment: actually confirmed as deployed and available